# Show an installed app's icon in Launchpad

Tags: macos, launchpad

I recently installed an app called [NetLogo](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/). I installed it via Homebrew Cask by running:

`brew cask install netlogo`

The app installation created a folder in `/Applications` directory. It comes with 5 .app bundles as shown:

[image]

The most used app out of the 5 is the one named **NetLogo 6.1.0.app** (second row, second last item from right). However, the icon for it doesn't show up in Launchpad. The icons for the other 4 showed up in Launchpad normally after the installation.

I can search for and launch the app fine using Spotlight.

Later I moved the 4 app icons in a Launchpad folder named NetLogo.

[image]

What could possibly be preventing NetLogo 6.1.0.app icon from appearing in Launchpad, and how can I make it show up? I have tried reinstalling by running:

`brew cask zap netlogo`

followed by

`brew cask install netlogo`.

I am running macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

Comment: My Brew Apps are listed in the other folder.

Comment: @ThomasNelson Other folder in Launchpad? In my case there are only default apps in Other folder.

Comment: I dont know why iSSTP shows up in the Other folder but that's what I installed from brew and that's where it shows up.  Like I said I am totally baffled as to why it shows up there and some things dont.  It doesn't bother me though because I dont use launchpad anyways.

Comment: @ThomasNelson I don't use Launchpad much either. What I am curious to learn is what could prevent an app from showing up in Launchpad.

Comment: I wonder if the Apps have to be signed...

Answer (score 1):

To add an icon/app to Launchpad, you can simply drag it to the Launchpad icon.

Comment: Launchpad icon in the Dock?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Did it work for you?

Comment: Nope it didn’t.